# How to get the field arguments in connection type in graphql ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

Currently I have the user's query type which returns a list of all the users. I have defined a custom `connection` and used it in the `user type`.

```rb
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    description "Get all the users"
    field :users, Types::UserConnection, null: false do
      argument :search, String, required: false
      argument :limit, Integer, required: true
      argument :offset, Integer, required: true
    end

    def users(search:, limit:, offset:)
      User.search(search).limit(limit).offset(offset)
    end
  end
end
```

My user connection looks something like this...

```rb
class Types::UserEdgeType < GraphQL::Types::Relay::BaseEdge
  node_type(Types::UserType)
end

class Types::UserConnection < GraphQL::Types::Relay::BaseConnection
  edge_type(Types::UserEdgeType)

  field :items_currently_on_page, Integer, null: false
  field :total_pages, Integer, null: false
  field :items_per_page, Integer, null: false

  def items_currently_on_page
    object.items.size
  end

  def total_pages
    (User.all.count.to_f / items_per_page).ceil
  end

  def items_per_page
    3
  end
end
```

Currently I have hard-coded the `items_per_page` which corresponds to the `limit` defined in the user's `arguments`. My question is how can I get the user's `limit` argument and replace with the hard coded value.

Comment: I got a similar problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Nope. Haven't used `graphql-ruby` after that. If you find an answer make sure you answer the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending the query using variables, then you can use `context.query.provided_variables`. That's a hash containing the variables you sent.

Comment: This is really great and useful to know as it is deeply buried in the API doc.

Comment: This is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

In the resolve function of a field you have access to the `context` variable.

If you have a graphql query like this:

```
{
  users(offset: 10, limit:10) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

you should be able to access the arguments and fields like that:

```
# .query: Access GraphQL::Query instance
# .lookahead: Access Class: GraphQL::Execution::Lookahead instance
#   Lookahead creates a uniform interface to inspect the forthcoming selections.
# .ast_nodes: Access to Array<GraphQL::Language::Nodes::Field> (.length always 1 for one query)
# .selections: Access to Array<Nodes::Field> (.length always 1 for one query)
#   .name returns to name of the query defined in query_type.rb for example "users"
# .children: Access to Class: GraphQL::Language::Nodes::AbstractNode instance
#   AbstractNode is the base class for all nodes in a GraphQL AST.
#   Seems to be the root of the field selection of a query.
#   Contains all queried connection fields like nodes, edges, pageInfo, totalCount
#   Also contains the provided arguments like first,last,after,before,limit,offset.
# nodes.selections: Access to Array<Nodes::Field>
#   Contains all requested nodes like id, slug, name, [...]

arguments = context.query.lookahead.ast_nodes[0].selections[0].arguments
fields = context.query.lookahead.ast_nodes[0].selections[0].children.find {|c| c.name == "nodes"}.selections
```

To get the value of the limit argument this should work:

```
def items_per_page
  context.query.lookahead.ast_nodes[0].selections[0].arguments.find {|a| a.name == "limit"}.value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function for get the count of the items_per_page

```
def items_per_page
    object.nodes.size
end
```